# How to make emacs auto complete file names in OSX?

Tags: emacs

Recently I switched from Linux to OSX and I see that I lost auto complete of file names in emacs. How do I make emacs complete file names and some commands. For instance, in Linux, it would remember `M-x print-buffer` but now I need to type `print-buffer` in full every time. I don't remember if I'd installed any plug in for this.

Comment: Do you mean `TAB` completion?

Comment: @Dror No. In the linux computer when I enter M-x I get suggestions like `M-x {org-mode | recover-this-file | print-buffer .... }` but in OS X, I have to enter `M-x org-mode` in full, there are no suggestions. But in OS X file suggestions work as well in Linux. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

A variety of solutions, may be you were using smex before?  Search for "emacs smex" to see what it does, or go here: 
http://emacs-fu.blogspot.ca/2009/05/finding-commands-with-smex.html

Comment: ido seems to be what I want http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2009/02/switching-buffers.html but doesn't seem to work with commands

Comment: @Zeynel smex builds on ido... So what you want to do is enable `ido-mode` on start-up *and* install smex. If you want to enable suggestions everywhere, you also might want to look at [ido-ubiquitous](https://github.com/technomancy/ido-ubiquitous).